# Cannot purge old kernels due to "unmet dependencies."

Tags: 16.04, apt, server, kernel, dependencies

My virtualbox VM (Ubuntu 16.04) is running out of disk space. Found there are old kernels. I've reached a standstill, because I cannot delete them due to `unmet dependencies`. Even if I try to `--ignore-missing`, it still errors out.

My current kernel is `4.4.0-193-generic`.

All the other kernels are:

```
linux-headers-4.4.0-169
linux-headers-4.4.0-169-generic
linux-headers-4.4.0-170
linux-headers-4.4.0-170-generic
linux-headers-4.4.0-171
linux-headers-4.4.0-171-generic
linux-headers-4.4.0-173
linux-headers-4.4.0-173-generic
linux-headers-4.4.0-174
linux-headers-4.4.0-174-generic
linux-headers-4.4.0-176
linux-headers-4.4.0-176-generic
linux-headers-4.4.0-177
linux-headers-4.4.0-177-generic
linux-headers-4.4.0-178
linux-headers-4.4.0-178-generic
linux-headers-4.4.0-179
linux-headers-4.4.0-179-generic
linux-headers-4.4.0-184
linux-headers-4.4.0-184-generic
linux-headers-4.4.0-185
linux-headers-4.4.0-185-generic
linux-headers-4.4.0-186
linux-headers-4.4.0-186-generic
linux-headers-4.4.0-187
linux-headers-4.4.0-187-generic
linux-headers-4.4.0-189
linux-headers-4.4.0-189-generic
linux-headers-4.4.0-190
linux-headers-4.4.0-190-generic
linux-headers-4.4.0-31
linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic
linux-image-4.4.0-169-generic
linux-image-4.4.0-170-generic
linux-image-4.4.0-171-generic
linux-image-4.4.0-173-generic
linux-image-4.4.0-174-generic
linux-image-4.4.0-176-generic
linux-image-4.4.0-177-generic
linux-image-4.4.0-178-generic
linux-image-4.4.0-179-generic
linux-image-4.4.0-184-generic
linux-image-4.4.0-185-generic
linux-image-4.4.0-186-generic
linux-image-4.4.0-187-generic
linux-image-4.4.0-189-generic
linux-image-4.4.0-190-generic
linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic
```

Here is what happens when I try to remove them:

```
dpkg -l linux-{image,headers}-"[0-9]*" | awk '/^ii/{ print $2}' | grep -v -e `uname -r | cut -f1,2 -d"-"` | grep -e '[0-9]' | xargs apt -y --ignore-missing purge
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-headers-generic : Depends: linux-headers-4.4.0-194-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-194-generic but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: thermald but it is not going to be installed
```

I don't have enough space to install `linux-headers-4.4.0-194-generic`. How can I remove these???

Comment: Don't use wildcards. Simply choose one installed (but unused) set of kernel packages that has no problems. Uninstall those. Now you have space. Rinse and repeat. Next, fix the reason that old kernels are accumulating.

Comment: I cannot uninstall, install, or anything at all. I get the same error no matter what I do.

Comment: Use dpkg instead of apt to remove the single set of packages. Your output seems to show a version conflict, not an out-of-space error. Your question should explain your troubleshooting process a bit more clearly.

Comment: Using dpkg instead of apt worked. Just gotta get that unmet dependency fixed. Thanks for that suggestion.

Comment: Alright, I installed the missing dependency, ran autoremove to get rid of the other junk, and I went from 98% disk usage to 27%. :) Thank you so much for the small tip that was a huge help. By the way, you're more than welcome to post this as an answer since it solved it for me.

Comment: I would suggest detailing exactly what you did as an answer to your own question, while it's fresh in your mind (and your shell history).

Answer (score 0):

Alright, using `apt` was not working when trying to remove old kernels. I had to use `dpkg` instead, like so:

```
dpkg -l linux-{image,headers}-"[0-9]*" | awk '/^ii/{ print $2}' | grep -v -e `uname -r | cut -f1,2 -d"-"` | grep -e '[0-9]' | xargs dpkg --remove
```

I attempted to run `apt autoremove`, however, I got the same `unmet dependencies` message. So I ran `apt -f install`, and then `apt autoremove` again, this time successfully.

Now I can install/uninstall packages just fine, and I gave myself a lot more disk space in the process.

Comment: It's also pretty trivial to add more disk space with VBox - assuming there's space left on the host OS. First, you make the virtual disk image larger in the media section of VBox. Then, you start the VM but you press F12, select a live .iso of your choosing, boot to that image and then grow the disk (with gparted) to use the now-larger disk. It's fairly straightforward.

Comment: My concern at the moment was to fix the initial problem of not being able to install anything (which was htop). I did not need all of those kernels. I don't require much space, because it's just a little NTP server. I have no intention of increasing the disk size. But I will take note of your suggestion if I ever need to. Thanks.